# How to generate a timeline with varying bar width?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I would like to plot a timeline such as the one below, except that the bar width would vary according to the value of a particular variable (`n` in the example).

Are you aware of a convenient way to do it?

The current timeline was drawn thanks to the `vistime` package, in which the
`linewidth` parameter has to be of length one. Ideally it would accept
`df$n*3` for instance.

Here's the code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(vistime)

df <- data.frame(debut = c(rep(2010,3), rep(2011,2), 2012),
                 fin = c(2011,2012,2013,2012,2013,2013),
                 n = c(3,1,2,6,7,5),
                 event = paste("n =", c(3,1,2,6,7,5), sep=" "),
                 color = c("#D73027", "#F46D43", "#FDAE61", "#FEE08B", "#D9EF8B", "#A6D96A"))
df$debut <- ymd(df$debut, truncated = 2L)
df$fin <- ymd(df$fin, truncated = 2L)

vistime(df, col.event="event", col.start = "debut", col.end = "fin", optimize_y = F, linewidth = 20, col.color = "color")
```

Thanks for helping!

The output:

[image: The output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ggplot. Simply draw line segments with `n` controlling the `linewidth` aesthetic.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(debut, -seq_along(debut), color = color)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = fin, yend = -seq_along(debut), linewidth = n)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = event), color = "black", nudge_x = 10, 
            hjust = 0, size = 8) +
  scale_linewidth_continuous(range = c(10, 30), guide = "none") +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, expand = c(0.2, 0)) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 24) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: How about `geomtextpath::geom_textsegment` to center the labels? ;)

Comment: Oohh. I never thought of that @stefan. That's a good idea. Less code, too. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

More or less the same answer as by @AllanCameron but using his (and @teunbrand's) `geomtextpath` package to add the segments and the labels via one `geom` and besides that offers a convenient way to center the labels:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(geomtextpath)

df$id <- seq(nrow(df))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_textsegment(
    aes(
      x = debut, xend = fin, y = id, yend = id,
      label = event, linewidth = n, color = color
    ),
    textcolour = "black", 
    gap = FALSE,
    show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  scale_linewidth_continuous(range = c(5, 10)) +
  guides(linewidth = "none") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

Additionally it offers a lot of options to style the labels and e.g. has a `gap` argument to "break" the segment for the labels:

```
geom_textsegment(
    aes(
      x = debut, xend = fin, y = id, yend = id,
      label = event, linewidth = n, color = color
    ),
    textcolour = "black", 
    gap = TRUE,
    show.legend = FALSE
 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This might look a little better.

```
df <- df[nrow(df):1, ]  ## reverse df
s <- sapply(df[1:2], \(x) as.Date(paste(x, '0101'), '%Y %m %d'))  ## convert columns to numeric date
ds <- do.call('seq.Date', c(as.list(as.Date(range(s))), '6 months'))  ## get dates for x-axis
hlfw <- (df$n) + 1  ## get half-widths of the bars
ys <- (cumsum(hlfw*2) - hlfw) + seq_along(hlfw)  ## get y values
plot.new(); plot.window(range(s), c(0, max(ys + hlfw))); box()  ## plot the thing ...
abline(v=ds, col=8, lty=3)
clr <- rainbow(length(hlfw), .7, .85, end=c(.25), rev=TRUE)
rect(s[, 1], ys - hlfw, s[, 2], ys + hlfw, col=clr, border=clr)
text(rowMeans(s), ys, paste('n =', df$n), cex=.8)
axis(1, at=as.numeric(ds), labels=strftime(ds, '%b %Y'))
```

[image]

Note that I didn't need the *event* and *color* columns, nor did I use an extra package.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- data.frame(debut=c(rep(2010, 3), rep(2011, 2), 2012), 
                 fin=c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2012, 2013, 2013), 
                 n=c(3, 1, 2, 6, 7, 5)
                 # , event=paste("n =", c(3, 1, 2, 6, 7, 5), sep=" "), 
                 # color=c("#D73027", "#F46D43", "#FDAE61", "#FEE08B", "#D9EF8B", "#A6D96A")
                 )
```

Comment: Really nice and a good idea to use rects instead of segments.

Comment: I had to slighty modify the code due to my R version I think (change (i) `\(x)` to `function(x)` in line 2 and (ii) specify the origin parameter in `as.Date` in line 3, but works fine! Thanks for it!

Comment: @vaaaaaal Yes, in older R versions, `function()` couldn't be abbreviated by `\(x)` and `as.Date` had no default `origin='1970-01-01'` (unix epoch). Better always use update R version if possible.